# warning: control may reach the end of non-void function in C

Tags: c

Specifically about the `put` function: I've reviewed the answers to this question and followed some of the suggestions e.g. putting an `else` condition in the `put` function, with no luck.

I still get the above warning at compile time. I suspect there is something else going on in the code to cause it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "hashtable.h"

/* For a given string refered to by the pointer "string",
 * calculate the hashcode and update the int "value".
 * 
 * Return 1 if successful, return 0 if unsuccessful.
 */
int main(){

}

int hash(char *string, unsigned long *value) {

   value = 0;
   if(string == NULL) {
     return 0;
   }

   while(string != NULL) {
     *value = *value + *string;
     string++;
   }
   return 1;
}

/* Add the string to the hashtable in the appropriate "bucket".
 * 
 * Return 1 if successful, and 0 if unsuccessful.
 */
int put(char *string, hashtable *h) {

   unsigned long hashValue = 0;
   int hashcode = hash(string, &hashValue);
   int index = hashValue %CAPACITY;
   node *head = &head -> next[index];
   node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
   if(newNode == NULL)
     return 0;  
   else
     return 1;
}


/* 
 * Determine whether the specified string is in the hashtable.
 * Return 1 if successful, and 0 if unsuccessful.
 */
int get(char *string, hashtable *h) {

  int i = *string;
  int newNode;
  for(i = 0; i <= newNode; i ++)
    if(*string == newNode) {
       return 1;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: well you've set the main return value type to int and there is nothing in it.

Comment: Add `return 0;` in your `main`.

Comment: `main` is an exception: it may fall off, means same as `return 0;`

Comment: BTW: in hash() function: replace `value = 0;` by `*value = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

This warning is due to your `main` function, which doesn't return anything.

Change this

```
int main(){

}
```

to this

```
int main(void) {
  return 0; // everything OK
}
```

As you can see, I wrote `main(void)`.

`void` here means that `main()` is **not** receiving any arguments! `main` can receive [command line arguments](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson14.html).

An irrelevant logical error is here:

```
int hash(char *string, unsigned long *value) {

  value = 0; // here you maybe forgot the *
  if(string == NULL) {
    return 0;
  }
  ..
}
```

you probably want to set where the value points to, to zero, so change this

`value = 0;`

to this

`*value = 0;`

I have made a small [example](http://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/functions-in-c/) in my pseudo-site, in case you want to see more in functions and pointers.

Comment: I added return 0; to main. The warning went away and it compiles fine. Does putting void in as a parameter insinuate that the function doesn't return anything anyway?

Comment: Your point well taken regarding the value pointer. I'm still struggling with the pointer concepts so it's actually pretty huge. Does it make a difference when initializing variables; to initialize them as pointers if the intent is to use it as a pointer?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. :) @user3656341, I also edited my answer with a link which has a small example in pointers in C and functions.

Comment: @user3656341 you could accept an answer of the ones provided here, so that your question appears as answered in the questions feed, which is very important for the other users. :)

Answer (score -3):

You have mentioned int as the return type of main() function. So you will have to return some integer value from the main function at every exit from the function.

There are two solutions to the problem.

Solution 1: return 0/1 at the end of the function and at every exit from the function

```
int main(){
----
----
return 0;
}
```

Solution 2: Specify void as the return type of main() function, if you dont want to process the return type of main function.

```
void main() {
---
---
}
```

Comment: `main()` should be `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.

Comment: No, void main() doesn't work. It does work as int main(void) with the suggested return 0;.

Comment: It is dependent upon which compiler you are using. But yes, according to C99 standards it is not valid to write void main(), only int main with no arguments or 2/3 arguments is valid.